# MOSS 2007: How to programmatically store web part properties for a user?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, storage, personalization

I have a web part which shows data in one of 3 different formats. The format is selected by clicking one of 3 buttons in the web part. This works fine.

A request has come through to store the last selected state so that the user does not always have to click their favourite view.

It seemed logical to define a Property and define **Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.User)** but this does not seem to work for most users as they only have Read rights for the page.

What is the best way forward here? Is Sharepoint the right place to store such info or should I be using my own storage?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your own storage is an option but this means its some more development work for you. How about this option.

1. Modify your WebPart and add the option to the Web Part property.
2. Create a new permission level and add the following permission

> Update Personal Web Parts  -  Update
>   Web Parts to display personalized
>   information.

This will make sure that users with read only access can only update webparts.

1. Step 2 will allow them to odify all webparts. You can modify each webpart and remove the following option for webparts which you dont want you users to edit.

   Allow Editing in Personal View [Advanced]

This way you can lock all webparts except the one you want.